# whether i right join or left join i get the same output why and how to fix it?

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE teacher(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, -- PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENt
    name_ VARCHAR(45),
    age INT,
    class INT
    );
    
CREATE TABLE student(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    name_ VARCHAR(45),
    class INT
    );

INSERT INTO teacher(id, name_ , age, class) VALUES
(DEFAULT ,"Ali", 40, null),
(DEFAULT, "Reza", 30, 2),
(DEFAULT, "Yosef", 50, 3),
(DEFAULT, "Ibrahim", 60, 2);

INSERT INTO student(id, name_, class)VALUES
(DEFAULT, "Hasan", 2),
(DEFAULT, "Hosein", null),
(DEFAULT, "Hamed", 4),
(DEFAULT, "Idris", 1);

SELECT * FROM teacher 
LEFT JOIN student 
ON teacher.id = student.id ;
```

i dropped the tables and tried again and again,

Comment: Teacher id is unique to each teacher record while student.id is unique to each student record. So, you can't use that to join the tables. The column "class" is common to both.

Comment: it worked, but now it even shows "Yosef"'s row as null, is it because yosef doesnt have any common class with the students??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Very unclear what you are trying to achieve. Some classes have more than one teacher, others have none.  Similarly, some students have no classes, others have more than one. But, no other information is in common to relate the tables. This might argue for a FULL OUTER JOIN rather than a RIGHT JOIN or LEFT JOIN.